# NSPredicate not working on iPhone 5 Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm using this code to fetch data from db.

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<UserHoldings> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Constants.Entities.UserHoldings)
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %d AND type == %d ", schemeId , sourceType.rawValue)
let result = try context.fetch(request)
```

`result.count` is returning 0 while running on iPhone 5 simulator but returning 3 on iPhone 6 simulator. Both running iOS 10.2.

If I remove `request.predicate` line it is working fine on both iPhones.

This is very weird behaviour. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: It's an array of Core Data object.

Comment: Do you actually have any data matching the given id and type? Are both of those properties integer types in your model?

Comment: yes, its working on iPhone 6 perfectly.

Comment: if I remove predicate This result give same number of objects in both simulators.

Comment: Each simulator has its own data. Just because it works in one doesn't mean you have the same matching data in the other. So I repeat my question. Do you actually have any data matching the given id and type on the iPhone 5 simulator?

Comment: Yes, Its having same set of data on BOTH simulators, If I remove the predicate from the query I have same data in both, and Yes I have the matching data for the predicate.